# Does default constructor for inner class need an object of an outer class?

Tags: java, reflection

I was fiddling around with java, and I created two classes, `Outer` and `Inner`

```
public class Outer {
    public class Inner { 
    }
}
```

Inner class is using default constructor. I can create new instance of `Inner` class inside `Outer` just by calling non-args default constructor `new Inner()`. But when I tried do same thing using reflection, I noticed constructor require  `Outer` type object.

Is that mean inner class default constructor is not non-args? Why there is disjoint between calling constructor in normal way and reflection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "disjoint between calling constructor in normal way and reflection", only between calling constructor from inside the `Outer` class and from outside of `Outer` class.

Since the `Inner` class is not `static`, it has a reference to `Outer`. If you want to create an instance of `Inner` from outside of `Outer`, you must write it like this:

```
Outer outerObj = new Outer();
Outer.Inner innerObj = outerObj.new Inner();
```

The requirement to provide `outerObj` to the constructor of `Inner` is exactly the same as when you instantiate the `Inner` class through reflection. The only difference is that the syntax places `outerObj` on the left of operator `new`, while reflection passes `outerObj` to the constructor. Java compiler adds a hidden argument to the constructor that it generates automatically, in the same way that it adds a hidden field to the generated class in order to hold a reference to the `Outer` object.

Note that this is true only for non-static inner classes. When your inner class is `static`, there is no hidden parameter and no hidden field, so reflection lets you create instances of the inner class without an `Outer` object.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner class is not static, so you can create Inner instances only if you have your Outer object.

Answer (score 1):

> I can create new instance of Inner class inside Outer just by calling non-args default constructor new Inner()

Inside yes, but his won't compile outside of Outer or from a static method of `Outer`:

```
new Outer.Inner();
```

This is because when you call `new Inner()` inside `Outer` `this` is implicitly passed to the constructor such that this:

```
public class Outer {
    public class Inner {
    }

    public example(){
        new Inner();
    }
}
```

Is equivalent to this static version:

```
public class Outer {
    public static class Inner {
        private Outer mOuter;
        public Inner(Outer outer){
            mOuter = outer;
        }
    }

    public example(){
        new Inner(this);
    }
}
```

The hidden reference to the `Outer` allows the inner to invoke methods on `Outer` as though they are it's own.